# haystack and google appengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-haystack

I developed an app in Django, mainly for educactional purposes, and I want to host it on GAE. The app uses MySql and Haystack/Whoosh. I'm following this [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) guide, but I'm not sure if Haystack/Whoosh will work on the NoSQL from GAE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use Haystack on GAE, but you can't use whoosh as the search backend. Instead, you'll need to use a hosted Solr or ElasticSearch as a backend search server. Try searchbox.io, they tell you how to get it working [with Haystack here](http://dev.searchbox.io/python/).

Comment: Do go through https://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine, version of whoosh that run on Google AppEngine

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about haystack on appengine but  there is a [nonrel-search](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search#docu) which I is designed to work on appengine and NoSQL databases.

Also I don't think GAE supports reletional database like Mysql.

Comment: Actually there's an experimental Cloud SQL offering that works with App Engine: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/ (the "experimental" label just means that while we're making it work better we're not committed to 100% backward API compatibility yet; not that it might go away).

Answer (score -1):

Whoosh is a file-based search backend so as long as you have write access to a directory then you should be able to use it.

You need to configure the directory of the search index in your Django application and run the appropriate command (`./manage.py rebuild_index` or `./manage.py update_index`) to build the search index into that directory.

Comment: GAE doesn't allow access to the filesystem.

Comment: (At least, no *write* access. :-)